# Problems to implement Higher-Order Components (HOCs) in React to reuse and abstract component logic

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Hello my code is failing i am using the withLoadingIndicator HOC is used to add a loading indicator to the MyComponent component. The HOC takes the MyComponent component as an argument and returns a new component that adds the loading indicator. Is this correct or what am i missing?

```
function withLoadingIndicator(Component) {
  return function WithLoadingIndicator(props) {
    if (props.isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.data}</div>;
  }
}

const MyComponentWithLoadingIndicator = withLoadingIndicator(MyComponent);

export default MyComponentWithLoadingIndicator;
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error? Does this code not do what you want it to do?

Comment: yea i am getting error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoading' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't passing any props into the Component at runtime. You can either:

**1) Pass the isLoading prop to the component:**

```
<MyComponentWithLoadingIndicator isLoading={false} />
```

**2) Make the prop optional:**

Change:

```
  if (props.isLoading) { .. }
```

To:

```
  if (props?.isLoading) { .. }
```

**3) Or provide a default value:**

```
function withLoadingIndicator(Component) {
  return function WithLoadingIndicator(props = {isLoading: false}) {
    if (props.isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}
```

OR use `defaultProps`, by adding this after your component declaration:

```
MyComponentWithLoadingIndicator.defaultProps = { isLoading: false };
```

Comment: yes that worked the   if (props?.isLoading) { .. } was all i needed and i dont have error anymore thanks :)  thank you!